# Directory Compression flag like Windows

Tags: 14.04, backup, cloud, rclone

Ubuntu 14.04
XFS file system

I'm preparing a large parent directory (24TB) for backup to cloud. It's currently empty. The child contents will ultimately be archived project directories that *should* be static, but may change.

- Does Ubuntu (or *nix) have the ability to keep all contents of a directory compressed? 
  <s>- If not, how does the Ubuntu world minimize the size of data sync'd (rclone) to a cloud environment (while maximizing file visibility for restore-ability)?</s> (Struck, since this s/b a separate question)

[image: Windows directory compression attribute]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XFS does not support file compression.

[BTRFS supports compression](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression), and so does zfs. You would have to change to one of those file systems to do compression.

[VDO](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/look-vdo-new-linux-compression-layer) is a new compression layer from Redhat, which acts as a virtual file system. It does not appear to be available for Ubuntu for now, and will probably not be ported to 14.04, which is soon end of life.